# Trello Api Find Card By Name

Tags: rest, trello

How do I find card by name in trello api?
One way I could think of is that we simply get all the cards for a board using boards/[board_id]/cards and then try to match the name of each card with what we have. But that looks a very inefficient way to do it as it would involve too many comparisons.

Is there any other way such that we could simply take in a card name and board name and then get the required card object?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the cardid or shortlink you can use this endpoint https://trello.com/docs/api/card/

Also maybe this could be helpful https://trello.com/docs/api/search/index.html#get-1-search

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Search endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-search/), defining to search only cards (`modelTypes: 'cards'`) and specifying the card name in the `query` parameter.

For example: `https://api.trello.com/1/search?modelTypes=cards&query=MySpecialCard`

Note that, [according to the documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/api-introduction/#search), you cannot specify the fields you want to search via specific parameters, but it is possible to do that using the query string (`query` parameter). For example, to search for a card named *My Special Card* that has *This is my special card* as description, you can make this request: `https://api.trello.com/1/search?modelTypes=cards&query=name:"My Special Card" description:"This is my special card."`.

Although I couldn't find it on the documentation, it seems that the string that you can use as the `query` parameter follows the same format as the one available when doing searches via the regular user interface: https://blog.trello.com/the-secrets-of-superior-trello-searches.

Comment: How would you use the things it returns?