# Query Trello card by string in card description

Tags: trello

i need to find all cards on board that have exact string in description. It is possible to do with web interface, but how can i do that with rest api?

the only way i've found is to get all cards from board and iterate and find string in desc. But could i do that with GET /1/search ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As answered in a [related question about getting card by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004049/3751868), you can use the [search endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-search/) and pass the description in the `query` parameter: `https://api.trello.com/1/search?modelTypes=cards&query=description:"This is my special card."`

Comment: thanks, could you pls help, how should i search for only not closed cards?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://help.trello.com/article/808-searching-for-cards-all-boards), you can use the "is:open" operator to return only open cadds (not archived). Also, please post a new question for inquiries not directly related to the original question.